# Update/Assign a foreign key to a pre-existing table row and not have it overwritten [mysql]

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table called promotion_codes

```
CREATE TABLE promotion_codes (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  created_at datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  code varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  order_id int(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  allocated_at datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This table is pre-populated with available codes that will be assigned to orders that meet a specific criteria.

What I need to ensure is that after the ORDER is created, that I obtain an available promotion code and update its record to reflect that it has been allocated.

I am not 100% sure how to not grab the same record twice if simultaneous requests come in.

I have tried locking the row during a select and locking the row during a update - both still seem to allow a second (simultaneous) attempt to grab the same record - which is what I want to avoid

```
UPDATE promotion_code 
SET allocated_at = "' . $db_now . '", order_id = ' . $donation->id . ' 
WHERE order_id IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second table which holds all used codes. So you can use an unique constraint in the assignment table to make sure that one code is not assigned twice.

```
CREATE TABLE `used_codes` (`usage` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
 `id` INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQ, -- This makes sure, that there are no two assignments of one code
  allocated_at datetime NOT NULL);
```

You add the ID of an used code into the `used_codes` table, and query which code you used afterwards. When this two operations are in one transaction, the entire transaction will fail when there is a second try to use the same code.

I did not test the following code, you might to adjust it.

Also you need to make sure that you have your server meets the [requirements for transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).

```
-- There are changes which have to be atomic, so don't use autocommit
SET autocommit = 0;
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO `used_codes` (`id`, `allocated_at`) VALUES
  (SELECT `id` FROM `promotion_codes`
    WHERE NOT `id` in (SELECT `id` FROM `used_codes`)
   LIMIT 1), now());
SELECT `code` FROM `promotion_codes` WHERE `id` =
  -- You might need to adjust the extraction of insertion ID, since
  -- I don't know if parallel running transactions can see the maximum
  -- their maximum IDs. But there should be a way to extract the last assigned
  -- ID within this transaction.
  (SELECT `id` FROM `used_codes` HAVING `usage` = max(`usage`));
COMMIT
```

You can use the returned code if the transaction sucseeded. If there where more than one processes running to use the same code, only one of them succed, while the rest fails with insert errors about the duplicated row. In your software you need to distinguish between the duplicated row error and other errors, and reexecute the statement on duplication errors.

Comment: Rudi - thanks for the reply.  Tracking in a second table everything that is in the promotion_code table almost seems redundant.  Such as, you know if a code is used from the promotion table by order_id and allocated_at


I do see how the having the unique ID will be a constraint that will fail